# Delete rows in dataframe based on 2 column conditional match in separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames DF1 and DF2. I need to remove all rows in DF2 that match both the EEnum and Date from DF1. There are multiple date columns in DF2 but I need Date in DF1 to validate to Date5 in DF2.

DF1:

| EEnum | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2022 |
| 123 | 06/01/2022 |
| 123 | 06/15/2022 |
| 124 | 01/01/2022 |
| 124 | 01/02/2022 |

DF2:

| EEnum | Date5 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2022 |
| 123 | 05/01/2022 |
| 123 | 06/01/2022 |
| 123 | 06/25/2022 |
| 124 | 01/01/2022 |
| 124 | 01/03/2022 |

Result DF2:

| EEnum | Date5 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 05/01/2022 |
| 123 | 06/25/2022 |
| 124 | 01/03/2022 |

I tried the following but it is removing all rows in DF2 where the Date in DF1 exists regardless of EEnum.

```
DF2 = DF2.loc[~((DF2.EEnum.isin(DF1['EEnum']))&(DF2.Date5.isin(DF1['Date']))),:]
```

Any ideas as to where I am going wrong? Or a better way to go about this? Pretty new so any help is appreciated.

Comment: like this???https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62519791/finding-duplicates-in-two-dataframes-and-removing-the-duplicates-from-one-datafr hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True`, then filter:

```
(df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'Date': 'Date5'}),
           indicator=True, how='outer')
    .query('_merge == "left_only"')
    .drop(columns='_merge')
)
```

output:

```
   EEnum       Date5
1    123  05/01/2022
3    123  06/25/2022
5    124  01/03/2022
```

intermediate (`merge` only):

```
   EEnum       Date5      _merge
0    123  01/01/2022        both
1    123  05/01/2022   left_only
2    123  06/01/2022        both
3    123  06/25/2022   left_only
4    124  01/01/2022        both
5    124  01/03/2022   left_only
6    123  06/15/2022  right_only
7    124  01/02/2022  right_only
```